# How can I View a picture saved to a filestream in an MVC web application?

Tags: c#, image, video, asp.net-mvc-2, filestream

I have made a windows app that takes a picture and saves that image to a filestream.  Now I want to make either a website or MVC web application that will display this image from the filestream, but I do not know where to start.  Can anyone help me?  Should I create a website in Visual Studios or a web application?  What my end goal is is to take a live video from an IP camera and save it on a server, then create a website that displays the live feed.  But the live feed is from the server and not from the IP camera itself.  All in C# and with no third party software.  I am really struggling with this so any help would be much appreciated.  If this has been done and posted, please post the link.  I was able to do it with just windows applications, but not with a website.

Thanks,
David

Comment: I think this would be really difficult to do

Answer (score 0):

You have few decisions which you should make:

1. What do you like more web forms or MVC? Or maybe single page application
2. You should use some kind of player it could be flash or silverlight player
3. You can store video in database(it is wrong way, but sometimes it is ok) or in a file on server. Actually you do not needwin application you can manage it through site. Just create admin dashboard for streaming video.

Do you need realtime stream or save and upload on website?

Comment: The IP camera that is supplying the feed never turns off, so I think it would have to be real time.  I haven't worked much with websites or webforms in VS, just windows apps so which would you recommend for #1?

Comment: After win apps easily start with webforms, because it is same architecture and easy to understand. Next it will be needed to stream to server and show stream from site. For this task it will be needed to implement bufferisation. At least between site and clients will be one connection with your PC. Other connections should see bufferised video. It seems to be a little bit complex, but it has solution.

Comment: So should I use just the regular Web application and not the MVC web app?  Also, do you know of any links that might point me in the right direction?